# Python how to find my smtp port no and host

Tags: python

I am trying to use the smtplib package in python to send mail 
What should be the host and porr no that I need to specify to the SMTP constructor

Comment: Not (immediately) a  programming question. The  correct values  depend entirely on the hosting infrastructure. Nominate for migration to https://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

This is my working example, I have used this in production.

```
smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.starttls()
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.login("Sender's email id", "Sender's password")
header = 'To:' + <RECEIVERS EMAIL ID> + '\n' + 'From: ' + <SENDERS'S EMAIL ID> + '\n' + 'Subject:<SUBJECT>'
message = <MESSAGE>
smtpserver.sendmail(SENDER, RECEIVER, message)
smtpserver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the default smtp.gmail.com with port 587.

Please, try [yagmail](https://github.com/kootenpv/yagmail). Disclaimer: I'm the maintainer, but I feel like it can help everyone out!

It really provides a lot of defaults: I'm quite sure you'll be able to send an email directly with:

```
import yagmail
yag = yagmail.SMTP(username, password)
yag.send(to_addrs, contents = msg)
```

You'll have to install `yagmail` first with either:

```
pip install yagmail  # python 2
pip3 install yagmail # python 3
```

Once you will want to also embed html/images or add attachments, you'll **really** love the package!

It will also make it a lot safer by preventing you from having to have your password in the code.